# Dynamic allocation in c++ is not checking array boundary?

Tags: c++, file, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int* arr = new(nothrow)int [100];
     int  i;
     if(arr == 0){//heap is full or dynamic allocation fails
     cout<<"Cannot allocate memory\n";
     return 0;
    }
    ofstream file("myFile.bin",ios::out|ios::binary);//opening the file in binary mode

    for(i = 0;i<100;++i){//dynamic array which contains numbers form 0 to99
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    if( file.is_open() ){

        if( file.good() )
            file.write((char*)arr,400);

        delete [] arr;
        file.close();
    }

    ifstream file1("myFile.bin",ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    char* buff;
    if(file1.is_open()){

        size = file1.tellg();
        buff = new char[size];
        file1.seekg(0);

        if( file1.good() )
            file1.read(buff,size);

        file1.close();
        for(i=0;i<size;i= i+4){//gcc => sizeof(int) is 4
            cout<<(int)*(buff+i)<<" ";
        }
        delete [] buff;

    }



}
```

Here i have allocated only 100 bytes and i am storing integers from 0-99 .ie. 400 bytes (gcc).
I am accessing memory that is not allocated.No segmentation fault occured .
Why is it happening.?

Output is 0 1 2 3....99

Comment: Just lucky. Actually, just back luck.

Comment: "Here i have allocated only 100 bytes ". Where is "here"? I see two `new` expressions, `new(nothrow)int [100];` and `buff = new char[size];`. Which one do you think is 100 bytes?

Comment: the first one of type int..already got ans :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you haven't allocated 100 bytes. You've allocated 100 `int`s. There's no overrun here.

Answer (score 2):

The allocated memory chunk may be greater than size you requested. And you are lucky, yes.
C++ does no boundary check. This is developer's responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault can only occur if the access is made to a page that is not mapped. If you stray only a few bytes behind your allocation, the chance is pretty high that there is no page boundary there, so the MMU cannot detect the error.

You are still likely to trash the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Segfaults are granted as an error.

however it is strongly recommended that you use a vector in these circumstances. and use it's at interface.

```
std::vector<int> v(100);
v.at(100); //throws range check exception
v[100]; //does not throw for efficiency.
```